# Ubuntu 18.10 with kernel 4.18 stops working

Tags: kernel, suspend, freeze, 18.10

[Update]: Any Linux kernel higher than `4.17` does not function on Ubuntu `18.10` on this machine (not also on `19.04`). It makes Ubuntu freeze almost 10 second after login and nothing functions after that.

My machine is Asus Zenbook UX430UN. It has Windows 10 as the native OS. I installed Ubuntu 18.10 on it two months ago. It was functioning well. Then I wanted to increase the size of the disk, so I decided to install everything again. I installed windows again and shrank the disk in two parts and installed ubuntu 18.10 again. But this time when it comes up and I log into my account in Ubuntu, the fans turn on and spin so fast and also it stops working and hangs and I cannot open any applications. I installed it twice and cleaned all the SSD again and installed windows again and again Ubuntu. It was the same. Then I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it functions well. Then I upgraded from that and again it stalls and stops working as soon as I go to my account. But today I boot it up not with kernel 4.18 and with 4.15 and it works well also with Linux 4.15. But I want to know why it does not work with Linux 4.18 anymore?
If anyone knows what is it, what is the solution? how can I use Linux kernel 4.18 again?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What does `uname -r` report from the terminal?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Now that I boot with 4.15 it returns 4.15.0-45-generic
But I cannot open even the terminal when I boot with the default kernel which is supposed to be 4.18

Comment: What does `ll /boot/vmlinuz-4.18*` report?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix unfortunately I just uninstalled 4.18 with UKUU before reading you comment.

Comment: Understood. There are 20 version of `4.18` and I was trying to narrow the problem down to a specific version of `4.18` for yourself and others.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I am sorry! Now can you help me how to load it? do you have any links how can I boot with new kernel installed? Or do you have any suggestion which kernel is better?

Comment: Try `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade`. I'm not sure if that will still work but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I installed ubuntu again, the problem still available. The result of the commands you requested:

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  4.18.0-13-generic. and: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8544088 ott 18 00:42 /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-10-generic

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix and -rw------- 1 root root 8548088 dic 5 06:11 /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-13-generic

Comment: Now when you boot your computer go to Grub's **Advanced Options** menu and select either `4.18.0-10` or `4.18.0-13` to see which one works best for you.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix None of them works. Both start dummy processes and prevents me to do anything and computer freezes in 5 seconds. Yesterday I upgraded from 18.04 and this time directly installed 18.10. Also consider that it was working before uninstalling it, and modifying the hard drive and installing again.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Also to run the command and get a reasult I used recovery mode of 4.18.3. Also I did update and upgrade in this mode but problem still there.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Consider that uninstalling completely ubuntu and removing it from the dir in windows, the Ubuntu option still remains when I get boot menu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89170/discussion-between-horotat-and-wineunuuchs2unix).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [UKUU](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu) to remove the broken kernel and then reinstall it. Just make sure that you are not running the broken kernel or else it will not let you uninstall it.